# Group records when times are sequential within a given minute interval

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, sql-server-2017

In SQL Server 2017, I am trying to group multiple records into a single record when teacherid and customerid are the same and when the scheduled time is immediately 50 minutes after the previous record, ie.

Table: Schedule

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
id  custormerid teacherid   schedule
----------------------------------------------------------------
571654  1085        46      2022-02-22 07:00:00.000
571657  1085        46      2022-02-25 07:00:00.000
571658  1085        46      2022-02-26 07:00:00.000
571659  1085        46      2022-02-26 07:50:00.000
571660  1085        46      2022-02-26 08:40:00.000
571666  1085        46      2022-02-26 10:20:00.000
571661  1085        46      2022-02-28 07:00:00.000
571662  1085        46      2022-02-28 07:50:00.000
571663  1085        11      2022-02-28 08:40:00.000
571664  1085        46      2022-02-24 07:00:00.000
571665  1085        46      2022-02-24 07:50:00.000
```

Desired result

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    custormerid     teacherid   schedule            Qty
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1085        46      2022-02-22 07:00:00.000     1
    1085        46      2022-02-25 07:00:00.000     1
    1085        46      2022-02-26 07:00:00.000     3
    1085        46      2022-02-26 10:20:00.000     1
    1085        46      2022-02-28 07:00:00.000     2
    1085        11      2022-02-28 08:40:00.000     1
    1085        46      2022-02-24 07:00:00.000     2
```

DDL Script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Schedule](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [custormerid] [int] NULL,
    [teacherid] [int] NULL,
    [schedule] [datetime] NULL) 
    

INSERT [dbo].[Schedule] ([id], [custormerid], [teacherid], [schedule]) VALUES (571654, 1085, 46, CAST(N'2022-02-22T07:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Schedule] ([id], [custormerid], [teacherid], [schedule]) VALUES (571657, 1085, 46, CAST(N'2022-02-25T07:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Schedule] ([id], [custormerid], [teacherid], [schedule]) VALUES (571658, 1085, 46, CAST(N'2022-02-26T07:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Schedule] ([id], [custormerid], [teacherid], [schedule]) VALUES (571659, 1085, 46, CAST(N'2022-02-26T07:50:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Schedule] ([id], [custormerid], [teacherid], [schedule]) VALUES (571660, 1085, 46, CAST(N'2022-02-26T08:40:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Schedule] ([id], [custormerid], [teacherid], [schedule]) VALUES (571661, 1085, 46, CAST(N'2022-02-28T07:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Schedule] ([id], [custormerid], [teacherid], [schedule]) VALUES (571662, 1085, 46, CAST(N'2022-02-28T07:50:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Schedule] ([id], [custormerid], [teacherid], [schedule]) VALUES (571663, 1085, 11, CAST(N'2022-02-28T08:40:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Schedule] ([id], [custormerid], [teacherid], [schedule]) VALUES (571664, 1085, 46, CAST(N'2022-02-24T07:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Schedule] ([id], [custormerid], [teacherid], [schedule]) VALUES (571665, 1085, 46, CAST(N'2022-02-24T07:50:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Schedule] ([id], [custormerid], [teacherid], [schedule]) VALUES (571666, 1085, 46, CAST(N'2022-02-24T10:20:00.000' AS DateTime))
```

I saw some examples using CETs, but I didn't really understand how to get to that result

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: @Marcoscdoni In my answer I have added a new update called "Final Update". Please check my update and let me know does it serve the purpose properly or not. Best wishes :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not need any `CTE` to solve that problem. By using  `Group by` you can do that =>

```
SELECT [custormerid],[teacherid],MIN([schedule]) [schedule],
       COUNT(*) Qty
 FROM [dbo].[Schedule]
GROUP BY [custormerid],[teacherid],CAST([schedule] AS DATE)
```

**Update:** Now, if you want maintain the sequence of the output as you provided in the question then you can use `CTE` like below.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT MAX([id]) MyID,[custormerid],[teacherid],MIN([schedule]) [schedule],
           COUNT(*) Qty
     FROM [dbo].[Schedule]
    GROUP BY [custormerid],[teacherid],CAST([schedule] AS DATE)
) 
SELECT [custormerid],[teacherid],[schedule],Qty FROM CTE ORDER BY MyID
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Final Update:**
Now, I have used several techniques to achieve what asked for. You said in the comment that you need count them with the diff of 50 min. So, I did that with multiple `CTE`. The query is providing the perfect output I believe for small amount of data but I did not test is for large amount of data. Another thing is that, the performance of query might be slow for large amount of data. So, please try it and let me know =>

```
WITH myCTE AS
(
 SELECT *,
      --I have used DENSE_RANK for Ordering the rows by [schedule]
      DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [custormerid],[teacherid],CAST([schedule] AS DATE) ORDER BY ID,CAST([schedule] AS DATE)) DRNK
 FROM [dbo].[Schedule]
),
CTE AS
(
    --Finding the parentID using logic of 50 min and others
    SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN DATEADD(MINUTE, -50,  [schedule])<=LAG([schedule],1) OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
              AND [teacherid]=LAG([teacherid],1) OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
              AND [custormerid]=LAG([custormerid],1) OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
              THEN LAG(ID,1) OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
              ELSE NULL END AS parentid
    FROM myCTE
),
myY AS
(   
   --Grouping the items Using Tree concept
    SELECT CTE.*, id AS rootid FROM CTE
    WHERE parentid IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C.*, P.rootid FROM myY AS P
    INNER JOIN CTE AS C ON P.id = C.parentid
)
SELECT
    MAX([custormerid]) [custormerid],
    MAX([teacherid]) [teacherid],
    MIN([schedule]) [schedule],
    COUNT(*) Qty
FROM myY
GROUP BY rootid
```

Comment: Qty is not a field in the table, this value is not stored, but should be displayed when grouping records to identify the number of records that have been grouped

Comment: @Marcoscdoni Yes. That is why I am using `COUNT(*)` to identify the number of records.  I have also added an update to my answer. If you still facing problem let me know. I will try my best to help you. :-)

Comment: But, the main issue is to group only the records with an exact difference of 50 minutes between them. Records with a difference greater than 50 minutes or another teacherid should not be grouped.

Comment: Ok. Wait let me try it.

Comment: thank you soo much! I'll try using larger amount of data, but for now it is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @Schedule TABLE (
    id int NOT NULL,
    custormerid int NULL,
    teacherid int NULL,
    schedule datetime NULL) 

INSERT @Schedule (id, custormerid, teacherid, schedule) VALUES 
(571654, 1085, 46, '2022-02-22T07:00:00.000')
,(571657, 1085, 46,'2022-02-25T07:00:00.000')
,(571658, 1085, 46,'2022-02-26T07:00:00.000')
,(571659, 1085, 46,'2022-02-26T07:50:00.000')
,(571660, 1085, 46,'2022-02-26T08:40:00.000')
,(571661, 1085, 46,'2022-02-28T07:00:00.000')
,(571662, 1085, 46,'2022-02-28T07:50:00.000')
,(571663, 1085, 11,'2022-02-28T08:40:00.000')
,(571664, 1085, 46,'2022-02-24T07:00:00.000')
,(571665, 1085, 46,'2022-02-24T07:50:00.000');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT *
        , DATEDIFF(minute, '1900-01-01', schedule) % 50 AS gr
    FROM @Schedule
)
SELECT custormerid, teacherid, MIN(schedule) AS schedule, COUNT(*) AS Qty
FROM rs
GROUP BY  custormerid, teacherid, gr
ORDER BY MIN(schedule);
```

Output

```
+-------------+-----------+-------------------------+-----+
| custormerid | teacherid |        schedule         | Qty |
+-------------+-----------+-------------------------+-----+
|        1085 |        46 | 2022-02-22 07:00:00.000 |   1 |
|        1085 |        46 | 2022-02-24 07:00:00.000 |   2 |
|        1085 |        46 | 2022-02-25 07:00:00.000 |   1 |
|        1085 |        46 | 2022-02-26 07:00:00.000 |   3 |
|        1085 |        46 | 2022-02-28 07:00:00.000 |   2 |
|        1085 |        11 | 2022-02-28 08:40:00.000 |   1 |
+-------------+-----------+-------------------------+-----+
```

**Method #2**

It is ugly, and I don't like it, but give it a shot.

```
;WITH rs AS
(
   SELECT * 
      , LAG(schedule, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY custormerid, teacherid ORDER BY schedule) AS LagValue
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custormerid, teacherid, CAST(schedule AS DATE) ORDER BY schedule) AS seq
   FROM @Schedule
), cte AS (
    SELECT *
       , IIF(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LagValue, schedule) <= 50 OR seq = 1, 1, 0) AS [legit]
       , DATEDIFF(minute, '1900-01-01', schedule) % 50 AS gr
    FROM rs
)
SELECT custormerid, teacherid, MIN(schedule) AS schedule --, legit, gr
    , Qty = SUM(IIF(legit=0,1,legit))
FROM cte
GROUP BY custormerid, teacherid, gr, legit
ORDER BY custormerid, teacherid, MIN(schedule);
```

Comment: If you insert the following record into the table, you will see that it is not grouping correctly. On the 26th it will count a total of 4 records, but the interval is greater than 50 minutes.

INSERT Schedule (id, custormerid, teacherid, schedule) VALUES (571666, 1085, 46, CAST(N'2022-02-26T10:20:00.000' AS DateTime))

Comment: @Marcoscdoni, please try Method #2